# Number of Boolean functions

Tags: functions

How many different boolean functions $F(x, y, z)$ are there so that $F(x, y, z) = F(z, y, x)$ for all
values of the boolean variables $x$, $y$, and $z$? Briefly justify your answer.

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to state the symmetry requirement for $F$?

Comment: Unfortunately,I am completely clueless.All I know is that in all there are 2^8 functions for three variables.By symtery do you mean the number of values for which x y z are same.For instance 001 and 010 something like that.

Comment: Ok,let me know if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: So,in all we have 8 values,000;001;010;011;100;101;110;111.Now if we look at 110 and 011,the x and z values for  these satisfy the requirmeent F(x,y,z)=F(z,y,x).Counting in this gives me six values.Thus the total number of boolean functions comes out to be 2^6.Which is the answer given to us.

Comment: Yes, overall, it seems you got the right approach.  I say "it seems" because it's not entirely clear what you mean by "counting in this [way] gives me six values." In general, for three variables you get to make 8 choices, but to satisfy $F(x,y,z) = F(z,y,x)$ you need to sacrifice two of those choices because $F(1,y,0)$ must equal $F(0,y,1)$ for both $y=0$ and $y=1$.